# Can I declare incompatible python dependencies?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I wonder if I can declare that a package will not work if a specific version of a modules is present but without making that module itself a dependency.

For example, as package publisher, I discover that presence of `foo==1.2.3` in python is breaking something key, even if I personally do not use it myself.

Is there a way to declare that incompatibility so my package will fail to install if this module is detected?

I known that I could dynamically test this at runtime by attempting to import it but I am more interested if this can be declared in package metadata, like an anti-dependency (or a negative dependency)

Comment: Nop, there is no way.

Comment: There is no _declarative_ way to do this, but if you can write a test, you can and run it in your setup.py and exit with non-zero status if it present

Comment: @Marat depending on how you package your project, `setup.py` might not be run during install. It also wouldn't work if the breaking package was installed after the one in question. Also @sorin, no, there is no non-runtime way to do this.

Comment: @Arne I guess as a package creator you cal always choose to publish a source package.

Comment: It's not unusual for users of a package to build them on their own though, in which case they could chose to use a wheel format instead of source.

Comment: No clean way at _install time_ that I know of currently. It might be worth reading this document https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#rarely-used-fields and this discussion https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/154 and eventually weigh in. A metadata field such as `Conflicts-Dist: foo==1.2.3` could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is no declarative way to do this and doing it in setup.py is not recommended because that is not guaranteed to run on install.

Also, even if possible, it will not prevent user from installing the incompatible package later.

This means that the only reliable way to do it is to add a runtime check. For cli tools it should be easy, for libraries or it can be tricky as it could impose a small performance impact on import.